# Adding my code into a JFrame

Tags: user-interface, jframe

So I can make a frame appear. I have this program which runs on my Eclipse console. I need to pass this program from my console to my frame. How would I do that? Or if that is too long of an explanation can you point me somewhere where I may learn how to do it? Here is a little bit of my code. I need to add what is in the `if` statement into my frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Amendments"); frame.setVisible(true);

    String z = "y";

while (z.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))

{

Random x = new Random();

int y =x.nextInt(1);

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (y == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("What is the First Amendment?");
        String answer = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your answer: " + answer);
        System.out.println("Right answer: Right to rapps religion is split between practice and establish");

}
```